# How to select option with Javascript from web browser developer tools

Tags: javascript, developer-tools

I am trying to select a desired value from dropdown menu in browser developer tools with Javascript. The following picture  shows the content of the page.

[image: Web browser developer tool content]

But whenever I select another value with code and then click the save button, the changes are not actually saved. When I select normally with my mouse and click the save button, it changes normally.

I have tried the following stuff. These seemingly changed the value of selected dropdown menu (it shows 2 when I write the code) but cannot be saved afterwards.

1- `document.getElementById('channel24g_ctrl')[2].selected = true`

2- `document.getElementById('channel24g_ctrl').options.selectedIndex = 2`

3- `document.getElementById('channel24g_ctrl').options[2].selected = true`

4- `document.getElementById('channel24g_ctrl').options[2].click()`

5- `document.getElementById('channel24g_ctrl').options[2].setAttribute("selected", "selected");
document.getElementById('channel24g_ctrl').options[1].removeAttribute("selected");`

I might have tried some other combinations of those above.
Only the fifth actually makes target option "selected" but it still doesn't work when save button is clicked. I am no expert with javascript or ember but I have done similiar things before with other websites and succeeded. So maybe the problem is with Ember Framework?

What else can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, selecting an option alone is sometimes not enough. `change()` must be called after selecting the option in order to apply changes. The following piece of code made the trick:

```
document.getElementById('channel24g_ctrl').options[2].selected = true;
$(document.querySelector('#channel24g_ctrl')).change();
document.getElementById('wifi_wizard_save').click();
```

Comment: document.getElementById('SELECT-OBJECT').options[1].selected = true;
$(document.querySelector('#SELECT-OBJECT')).change();
document.getElementById('SELECT-OBJECT').getElementsByTagName('option')[1].selected = 'selected'

Comment: COPY JQUERY FROM HERE https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js

MAKE A NEW FILE IN THE FOLDER EXTENTION jquery.js

Comment: "content_scripts":[{ 
        "js": ["jquery.js","main.js"],
        "matches":["https://*/*"]
    }]

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById('personlist').getElementsByTagName('option')[11].selected = 'selected'`

Comment: It seems to be selecting 11th option. However save button does not save with this one too.

Comment: All of the code I tried are in the question. Web site is not mine. I just try to manipulate its elements by small javascript pieces.